# Temporarily compressing MySQL binlogs

Tags: mysql

I am currently importing a pretty big MySQL database dump. This takes time and during this time I need some extra disk space. Will I break something in MySQL if I temporarily gzip a couple of it's binlogs? I'm assuming I'm not going to compress binlogs that are purged, nor written, nor read by the MySQL instance.

Example:

```
$ ls
mysql-bin.000340
mysql-bin.000341
mysql-bin.000342
mysql-bin.000343.gz
mysql-bin.000344.gz
mysql-bin.000345.gz
mysql-bin.000346
mysql-bin.000347
mysql-bin.000348
mysql-bin.index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly safe to do so as long as you don´t gzip the file which is currently written (the last file).

Also in case of a replication setup ensure that the files you are gzipping are already fetched by the slave. You can verify this by checking the output of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS`on the slave, look here for `Master_Log_File`, this will give you the logfile of the master which is currently be fetched by the slaves io-thread. Every preceding file is absolutely safe to gzip.

Comment: Sweet! In my case I had temporarily stopped all replication slaves, so that last part was not an issue.